# Linux wait process

Tags: linux

I have a basic script to test Linux wait method, the code is as below.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "testing wait command 1" & 
process_id=$!
echo "testing wait command 2" &
wait $process_id
echo "command 1 completed"
echo "command 2 completed"
```

According to my understand, the output should like this

```
testing wait command 1
testing wait command 2
command 1 completed
command 2 completed
```

But the actual output is this

```
testing wait command 2
testing wait command 1
command 1 completed
command 2 completed
```

I do not understand why command 2 come in front of command 1.
If I remove & from echo "testing wait command 1" &, the output is what I expected.

Comment: There is nothing in your script guaranteeing the order in which 1 or 2 are executed.

Comment: You do not wait for command 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)` and have run your script several
times and always got `testing wait command 1` printed first.

That being said, when `&` is used Bash forks a new process and you
cannot expect a given order in which kernel scheduler will run
different processes or more technically speaking *threads* on the
system. It may seem to you that all processes on the system are run at
the same time but in fact system scheduler will constantly switch
between them and lets them use CPU. This switch is known as *context
switch* and it happens so frequently that humans don't even
notice. Process can be preempted at any time, not only to let other
process use CPU resources but also due to hardware interrupt which is
triggered by hardware and handled by kernel. You cannot even expect
that script execution will take the same amount of time every time you
run it.

Answer (score 0):

This means command 2 runs faster and is completed before command 1. If you want strict order - remove '&' after command 1.